# Setting up a Hyperledger Fabric Kafka Implementation

Tags: apache-kafka, yaml, hyperledger-fabric

I have been recently working on a custom implementation of hyperledger fabric with kafka implementation to no avail.

I was wondering if anyone has done this successfully and if so could you share your configtx.yaml, docker-compose.yaml(and any base files), and crypto-config.yaml.

Also looking for any extra articles anyone might have found on this topic that may help me progress.

Comment: "to no avail"… you need to be more specific. Did you hit errors? What did you try setting up? Which versions? etc.

Comment: At this stage debugging incorrectly implemented versions of a deployment would take too long. I'm looking for correct implementations so I can learn from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have done that. Configured multiple orderer(kafka-based) for one network. Here is the code: https://github.com/lissdy/fabric-composer/tree/master/fabric-network/kafka-orderers